# combo box .ValueMember not working for me

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox, insert, valuemember

Calling database value in combo box for DisplayMember and ValueMember , but ValueMember property not working here .......

```
        sql = "select NAME_DESC,ACCOUNT_CODE from ACCOUNT_CONTROLS ORDER by 
        NAME_DESC"


        cmd = New OracleCommand(sql, sgcnn)
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()


        CmbConAcc.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        CmbConAcc.DisplayMember = "NAME_DESC"
        CmbConAcc.ValueMember = "ACCOUNT_CODE"
```

---

--- trying to insert ValueMember data into database

Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_HEADS (HEAD_CODE,NAME_DESC,ACCOUNT_CODE,REMARKS)" &
                          "values( trim(" & TxtAccCode.Text & "),trim(' " & TxtNDesc.Text & " '),trim(' " & CmbConAcc.ValueMember & " '),trim(' " &
                          txtRemarks.Text & " ')) "
```

Comment: As an additional note please use SQL parameters as your current method is open to SQL injection which isn't something you want to risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `ValueMember` here:

```
CmbConAcc.ValueMember = "ACCOUNT_CODE"
```

why would you expect to get anything other than that out?

The `ValueMember` is the name of a property/column of the data source.  When the user makes a selection, the value from that property/column of the `SelectedItem` is exposed by the `SelectedValue` property.  That's what you need to use.

That's what the code example in the documentation for the `ValueMember` property demonstrates and that's why you should ALWAYS read the documentation.  VS has a Help menu for a reason.